# YouTube Video GData API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, gdata-api

I am trying to get YouTube functioning within my iOS App.  I am successfully retrieving the list of videos for a particular user, but I am struggling to implement the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in order to get the selected video to embed in a separate viewController.  Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DetailViewController *detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];

    GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    videoArray = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
    NSString *tempUrl = [videoArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"The URL is:%@",tempUrl);
    detailController.videoString = tempUrl;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];

}
```

Every time I run this, I get a breakpoint at 'detailController.videoString = tempUrl;'

I am able to see the tempUrl string is being populated with the following via NSLog:

```
The URL is:GDataMediaContent 0x69c76a0: {url:https://www.youtube.com/v/s36krFdPmYQ?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata type:application/x-shockwave-flash medium:video isDefault:true expression:full duration:1913}
```

How can I extract just the video URL from the GData API?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

I made the following changes and I am now getting a proper URL string:

```
GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *mediaContents = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
    GDataMediaContent *flashContent = [GDataUtilities firstObjectFromArray:mediaContents withValue:@"application/x-shockwave-flash" forKeyPath:@"type"];
    NSLog(@"The URL is:%@",[flashContent URLString]);
    detailController.videoString = [flashContent URLString];
```

Which gives me the following from NSLog:

```
The URL is:https://www.youtube.com/v/s36krFdPmYQ?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata
```

I am still however getting a breakpoint at 'detailController.videoString = [flashContent URLString];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this.  I added a Modal segue between the two ViewControllers and also modified my code slightly.  Here is the code I ended up using after adding the segue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];
    GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [[entry2 title] stringValue];
    NSArray *contents = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
    GDataMediaContent *flashContent = [GDataUtilities firstObjectFromArray:contents withValue:@"application/x-shockwave-flash" forKeyPath:@"type"];
    NSString *tempURL = [flashContent URLString];

    detailController.videoString = tempURL;
    detailController.titleString = title;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];

}
```

You can view the full working YouTubeDemo app code here:
https://gist.github.com/2501684